# Maven Not Compiling the java files

Tags: maven

This is My Folder structure -

```
![Project explorer][1]
--project>
  --src
    --main
      --java
      --resource
  --target
pom.xml
```

This is My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-loginform-xml</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringSecurity Custom Login Form XML</name>
    <url>http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>mkyong</id>
            <name>Yong Mook Kim</name>
            <email>mkyong2002@gmail.com</email>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl for jsp page -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringSecurityHelloWorld</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    </build>

</project>
```

While i am going to modify the code in java file or the controller those are not effecting while I am running the project. I think Maven is not compiling the Java code.

Is the folder structure is correct ?
Where the class files are generated in the project ?

Can any one suggest with explanation.

Comment: sorry i cant have permition to post Images

Comment: Looks like the 'pom.xml' is not next to 'src' but outside of the project folder. It should be at the top of the project.  Class files would get generated in 'target' (also next to 'src') at the top-level.

Comment: Sorry allign ment problem ;

--project>
   --src
      --main
         --java
      --resource
   --target
   pom.xml

that is right next to the src folder.

Comment: Okay, then. Next: Try to remove the `sourceDirectory` tag. You are using the default anyway it seems. And what error message do you get from Maven when you run it?

Comment: Actually i have refer some where and added that. Before adding that <sourceDirectory> it was  not working.

Comment: someone please tell me does maven compile java code? As written in question.

Comment: You are saying that while the application is running, you change some Java code and expect Maven to automatically compile it so that the changes are visible in your application immediately?

Comment: before deployng the project we perferms clean and maven instal from eclipse, aren't those compile the code ? Then how the .class file will be generated ? I am new to MAVEN. please clarify if I am wrong. @manish

Comment: When Maven is run, yes, it will compile code.  However, when an application is running and changes are made to Java files, those changes will not be picked up automatically (by Maven or any other build tool).  In a normal scenario, you will have to stop the application and start it again after changing Java files for the changes to take effect in your application.  If you want to work around this, explore options proposed by @JBA in the answer below.

Comment: Yes @manish I am always perferming those process. first make changes then run maven commands then deploy the project in tomcat and start the server. And those changes are not reflected like I am adding some print statement but not getting the output in console.

Comment: If it is an standalone Tomcat instance (not launched from your IDE), the statements may be going to the Tomcat log file `catalina.out`.

Comment: I am performing everything from IDE only not from windows console because i am using eclipse LUNA and its having maven-plugin. Actually I am facing this problem in every maven sample project. Do you have any idea.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your question and the comments below it I try to give you a answer:

*is the folder structure correct?*

Yes ist is. It follows the Maven standard directory structure described here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

It however misses a webapp-folder (see next point) which will not make your build fail but end in a `war` **not** containing a `WEB-INF` folder - hence it is not a standard webbapplication as defined by the Java EE standard (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html).

*Where are the class files generated in the project?*

After maven runned the phase `compile` (`mvn compile`) of the default lifecycle (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) the compiled class files will be placed under `/target/classes`.

If you continue to the phase `package` (`mvn package`) maven will build a `war` (`jar` is the default `packaging` type which was overwritten in your pom) containing your classes as well as your resources which is placed under `/target`

Note: If you are building a webapplication you place your website's content such as a deployment descriptor (`web.xml`) or HTML/JSP/JSF pages etc. under a folder `src/main/webapp` (the `WEB-INF` folder should be under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`).

*Regarding the comments disscussion*

If you expect to see changes in Java files on the fly Maven will not support you out of the box. Maven is a build tool - e.g. if you change something in your project you will request maven to build the project again to have the changes ready in a deployable form (e.g. you have a `war` file in your `/target` folder which you can then deploy).

If you want to see changes on the fly you should try a websearch for topics such as `Hotdeployment`, `JRebel`, `embedded jetty` since there are quite a few options available to archive this.

One general approach to have hotdeployment "out of the box" is to point the exploded directory of a hotdeploy-supported (web)(application) server to the exploded directory of your maven build. Right on the same level as you will find your `spring-login-security-xml.war` the is a folder `spring-login-security-xml` which contains the unpacked webapplication. This will however not spare you to have a build per change.

Answer (score 5):

This is the first issue that popped up for me when my class files were not being generated. My fix does not apply to this question, but I'm mentioning it here in case it helps someone else.

I had a quick copy and paste setup with a single top level `pom.xml`. In it I had set

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

which caused the java files to be ignored. The fix was to remove the packaging tag, letting it default to `jar`.

Comment: Bless you, this saved me for a side project at work where nobody else knows Maven :)